# Type in login and password

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

Just began typing following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://auth.sketchengine.eu/#login')

button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="r_0"]')[0]
button.send_keys('Lobster')
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="r_1"]')[0]
button.send_keys('123123123')
```

to make Python go to Sketch Engine and type in a login and password. I used **inspect** in Chrome and then copied the Xpaths, but Python is not doing the typing and says **'unable to locate element'** for both the Xpaths. What do I change?

Comment: Your element can be in a different iframe or your id can be changed dynamically. Please add the relevant part of the HTML.

Comment: As stated by @Dazed you should look for input element and thus remove [0] from your script.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Python person but try this for xpath. I think the issue is that id "r_0" is on the page a few times. If you look at the xpath with "//input" you will only return one.

```
//input[@id="r_0"]
//input[@id="r_1"]
```